# Can Angular Service call a function in the Controller that invoke the service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller

Here is my `controller`

```
RegisterController.$inject = ['$location', '$scope', 'Authentication'];

function RegisterController($location, $scope, Authentication){
  var vm = this;

  vm.register = register;

  function register(){
    Authentication.register(vm.email, vm.password, vm.confirm_password, vm.username);
  }

  function register_error_display(error_list){
    console.log("what is going on")
  }

}
```

Here is my `service`

```
function Authentication($cookies, $http, RegisterController){

var Authentication = {
  register: register
};

return Authentication;


// Register logic
function register(email, password, confirm_password, username){
  return $http.post('/api/v1/accounts/',{
    username: username,
    password: password,
    confirm_password: confirm_password,
    email: email
  }).then(registerSuccess, registerError);
}


function registerError(response){
  error_list = response["data"];
  RegisterController.register_error_display(error_list);
}
```

}

The flow is this `register (controller)` -> `post (service)` -> `registerError (service)` -> `register_error_display (controller)`

I believe this is returning me this error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: RegisterControllerProvider <- RegisterController <- Authentication
```

What is the reason of this error, is there a way around it?

Comment: The error is clear: you are trying to inject unknown service, there is no service `RegisterController` (it's not a service).

Comment: Is it possible to inject controllers into service? What are some alternatives if I want to use a function in the controller within the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't inject controllers in services. One of the reasons is that a controller is instantiated every time a directive is created, while the a service is instantiated once at startup.

Instead you can make the **Authentication.register** function return a promise. One can be created using the **$q** service.

Or, if you do not want to do anything after the authentication succeeds or fails in the Authentication service just return the promise you get from the **$http.post** call.

Returning the **http.post** response:

service
    function Authentication($cookies, $http){

```
   var Authentication = {
     register: register
   };

    return Authentication;


   // Register logic
  function register(email, password, confirm_password, username){
    return $http.post('/api/v1/accounts/',{
    username: username,
    password: password,
    confirm_password: confirm_password,
    email: email
   });
  }
```

controller

```
RegisterController.$inject = ['$location', '$scope', 'Authentication'];

function RegisterController($location, $scope, Authentication){
  var vm = this;

  vm.register = register;

  function register(){
    Authentication.register(vm.email, vm.password, vm.confirm_password,    vm.username).then(onSuccess, onError);
  }

  function onSuccess(result) {
    console.log("HTTP request succeeded");
  }

  function onError(result) {
    console.log("HTTP request failed");
  }
}
```

Your own promise:
service

```
function Authentication($cookies, $http, $q){

var Authentication = {
  register: register
};

return Authentication;


// Register logic
function register(email, password, confirm_password, username){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http.post('/api/v1/accounts/',{
     username: username,
     password: password,
     confirm_password: confirm_password,
     email: email
   }).then(function(result) {
       deferred.resolve(result);
   }, function(error) {
       deferred.reject(result);
   });

   return deferred.promise();
 }
```

}

controller

```
RegisterController.$inject = ['$location', '$scope', 'Authentication'];

function RegisterController($location, $scope, Authentication){
  var vm = this;

  vm.register = register;

  function register(){
    Authentication.register(vm.email, vm.password, vm.confirm_password, vm.username).then(onSuccess, onError);
  }

  function onSuccess(result) {
    console.log("Authentication success");
  }

  function onError(result) {
    console.log("Authentication success");
  }
```

}

I would recommend making and returning your own promise. That way you can abstract from the controller how the authentication actually takes place. 
For example you could still have a successful request but the response might be that the authentication failed.